# Configuring NextAuth.js Keycloak provider

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to use Keycloak provider with next-auth@4.0.0-next.26

In the [Keycloak provider documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/providers/keycloak), the link of [Keycloak Provider options](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/main/src/providers/keycloak.js) shows 404 error. May I know if there is a way to see a list of available options?

Does it makes sense to connect to PKCE client when implementing authentication using NextAuth.js or Next.js?

Comment: The Keycloak provider is only available in the `beta` branch. See https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/beta/src/providers/keycloak.ts. The options seem to be the same as the OAuth provider: https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/blob/beta/src/providers/oauth.ts#L91.